# Android Custom ListView search with CheckBoxes , Filter is not Working

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, baseadapter

I am working on Android Application , i have a custom listview with checkboxes , i can select check boxes and get selected values . but when i try to search some particular name application crashes .

here is my code , i think i am missing something .

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<InfoRowdata> arraylisto;
    private List<InfoRowdata> worldlist = null;

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<InfoRowdata> worldpopulationlist) {
        mContext = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.worldlist = worldpopulationlist;

        this.arraylisto = new ArrayList<InfoRowdata>();
        this.arraylisto.addAll(worldpopulationlist);

    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView Name;
        CheckBox cb;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return worldlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

 public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
final ViewHolder holder;
if (view == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.creditunionrow, null);
    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    holder.Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
    holder.cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);

    view.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}
// Set the results into TextViews
holder.Name.setText(worldlist.get(position).getName());
 // holder.cb.setChecked(worldlist.get(position).getChecked());


holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Selection = "";
                count=0;
                String selecteditems = "";
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (infodata.get(position).isclicked) {
                    infodata.get(position).isclicked = false;

                } else {
                    infodata.get(position).isclicked = true;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < infodata.size(); i++) {
                    if (infodata.get(i).isclicked) {
                   //System.out.println("Selectes Are == "+ data[i]);
                        selecteditems = selecteditems + data[i] + ",";
                    count++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Selected Are == " + selecteditems);
                Selection = selecteditems;
            }



});
if (infodata.get(position).isclicked) {

    holder.cb.setChecked(true);
} else {
    holder.cb.setChecked(false);
}




// Listen for ListView Item Click
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    }
});

return view;
}

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        worldlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            worldlist.addAll(arraylisto);
        } else {
            for (InfoRowdata wp : arraylisto) {
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    worldlist.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**here is my Model CLass**

```
public class InfoRowdata {

public boolean isclicked=false;
public int index;
public String name;
/*public String strAmount;*/

public InfoRowdata(boolean isclicked,int index,String name/*,String strAmount*/)
{
    this.index=index;
    this.isclicked=isclicked;
    this.name=name;
    /*this.strAmount=strAmount;*/
}


public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public Boolean getChecked() {
    return isclicked;
}

public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
    this.isclicked = checked;
}
```

}

**The Exception I am getting :**

```
                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                       at My.Profile.activity.UnionActivity$MyAdapter.getView(UnionActivity.java:240)
                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1281)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**This is how i am Searching listview with edittext :**

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            //Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count)
        {



            String text = inputSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.filter(text);
        }
    });
```

I dont know where i am missing something , i want to check random checkboxes and also apply search on them with correct reference of checked checkboxes , firstly i was not doing it with custom adapter , the searching was fine there but i lost the checked state of checkboxes when search is applied , now i am using customadapter , how can i get correct reference of check boxes on searching listview . I will verythankful for any help , i almost had spent two days in this , and search all the internet but could not get any example which implements listview with checkboxes and search functionality .

Comment: HII. Did you get the solution for the checkboxes selection when the user is search through the search bar. i have a problem that is when I searched the contact through search bar the contact displayed with checkboxes when I checked that box and delete the text in the search box then the checkbox is checked the first item of the contact list instead of selected contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The java.util.ArrayList.addAll(Collection c) method
>   appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of
>   this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified
>   collection's Iterator.

**WRONG**

```
    this.arraylisto = new ArrayList<InfoRowdata>();
    this.arraylisto.addAll(worldpopulationlist); // Problem Here
```

**Right**

```
this.arraylisto = new ArrayList<InfoRowdata>();
this.arraylisto.addAll(worldlist); // Rectify here
```

**And**

```
 @Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return worldlist.size();
}
```

Comment: Great this worked , Now i am not getting any exception and search is working , Thanks a lot  . but still i have problem with checked state of checkboxes, if you can give any hint how to keep track of checked checkboxes while searching

Comment: @Intellij Amiya .HII. i have the problem of the checkboxes selection when the user is search through the search bar. i have a problem that is when I searched the contact through search bar the contact displayed with checkboxes when I checked that box and delete the text in the search box then the checkbox is checked the first item of the contact list instead of selected contact. Did you give any adivce regrading that

Answer (score 0):

first don't use `onClickListener` on `CheckBox` use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` , second you have on empty list try @IntelliJ Amiya answer